# How to have discord.js have someone add and remove role of someone else

Tags: discord, discord.js

so recently eli bot is not avaliable for a next few days/month cz the owner of eli got banned from discord. I have use eli to jail members. So I want to make a jail command on my bot (adding a jail role and remove other role) and unjail command (remove jail role and add the member role back). I have searched entire internet how to add the command but couldnt find it. please help me, im so sorry if my english not to good

Comment: Have you tried anything? What do you have problem with? Have you tried to add a role to a mentioned user? Do you have any code to share here? This question is too broad at the moment and probably will get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on a code that does almost the same job as your request!
That code gives mute to a member ! What does this mean ? My code gives a role called "MUTED" and takes from the member the main role I use!

```
const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (target) {
 
            let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'member');
            let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'mute');
 
            let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
 
            if (!args[1]) {
                memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
                message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted`);
                return
            }
            memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
            memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
            message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`);
 
            setTimeout(function () {
                memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
            }, ms(args[1]));
        } else {
            message.channel.send('Cant find that member!');
        }
    }
}
```

In line 3 and 4

```
let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'member');
            let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'mute');
```

Mean that you need a main role for your members and a role that you want to be like "MUTE".
My code is taking permissions from member. It is a punishment method for me !

The "unmute" command is :

```
const target = message.mentions.users.first();
            if(target){
                let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'member');
                let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'mute');
     
                let memberTarget= message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
     
                memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
                message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been unmuted`);
            } else{
                message.channel.send('Cant find that member!');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey thanks for the commands, its totally works for jailing and unjail, but now the main problems is, i cant remove the other member roles, like if i mute/jail staff, the staff role is still there and not getting removed

Comment: It is working only with the main role ! 
If you want to add more roles in your code, you need to change your code : let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'member'); to      let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('roleID', 'roleID1' , 'roleID2');

Comment: I've done like what u said, but its only removing 1st role, the 2nd and the another role stay there not get removed, do I need to add the role id and the numbered it? or?, Im so sorry if disturb you, I'm still new  to programming.

Comment: you need to set another `let let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'member');` for more roles and in line `memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id, mainRole1.id, mainRole2.id);`